# Can someone please help me to stop continual automatic iCal.ics replies to 3 meetings emailed to my yahoo account

Tags: mac, calendar.app, yahoo-mail

My Calendar app is autoreplying to 3 meeting invites sent from 3 different people to a yahoo mail account (auto reply every few hours). Originally the auto reply was sending multiple 'meeting accepted' emails through yahoo. I have deleted the meetings in Calendar, and tried to find and delete the .ics attachments in downloads and elsewhere, and deleted the original email invite. It now sends autoreplies that the meeting(s) is declined. I have also asked the senders to delete at their end but the glitch is in my computer.

It is iCal-Reply.ics that seems to be the culprit - but I don't know how to fix it without deleting my whole calendar app

Email reply says:
xxx has declined your invitation to the event: xxx, scheduled for xxx at xxx

Any help and insights would be gratefully received.